# Постоянен ли UID юзера внутри контейнера docker?

Tags: linux, docker

Для разработки хочу держать файлы веб-проекта в папке хоста, подключённой как Volume в контейнерах nginx и php-fpm. В последнем скрипты запускаются от имени юзера `www-data` с UID=33.

PHP (Laravel) хочет писать логи в одну из подпапок. Разрешаю запись юзеру с UID=33: `sudo chown 33:33 -R .../app/storage`. В хост-системе такой юзер отсутствует.

Вопрос: при развёртывании на других хостах одного и того же имиджа, всегда ли UID внутриконтейнерного юзера `www-data` будет один и тот же, `33`?

А что, если я запущу несколько контейнеров из одного имиджа – у всех этот внутренний юзер `www-data` будет с одинаковым UID виден из хоста?

Какова best practice для прав доступа на папку логов в таком сетапе? Хочется по привычке для разработки держать код на хосте. Хотя, конечно, можно и для него контейнер соорудить с sftp/ssh доступом.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

www-data создается при установке пакета. В одном и том же дистрибутиве uid будет тот же.

Можно воспользоваться `sudo chown www-data:www-data -R .../app/storage` внутри гостя.

Comment: На момент запуска гостя этой папки может ещё не быть, но спасибо за идею – можно же при установке пакета создавать файл-образец `samplefile` в известной существующей папке под корнем, и потом с него копировать права: `chown --reference=samplefile -R .../app/storage`

Comment: если её нет - её можно создать, пользователя www-data можно тоже создать до установки вэб-серверов

Comment: Пользователи `www-data` в хосте и госте не факт же, что будут иметь единый UID?

Comment: выполняйте всё в госте, я бы не трогал хоста...

Answer (score 2):

Докер, помимо некоторых удобных штук, вводит некоторые правила игры, которым стоит следовать, потому что они удваивают прирост великолепности от использования этого движка.

Во-первых - да, пока в создании контейнера не замешан рандом, все существующее в нем будет воссоздоваться идентично вне зависимости от количества запусков и параллельных контейнеров одного образа.

Во-вторых, имена пользователей создаются специально для того, чтобы абстрагироваться от айдишников. Признаюсь, я не до конца понял проблему, очевидо, проблема в правах на volume, но я с этим никогда не сталкивался, и в следующей части вопроса объясню, почему.

Во-первых, вам стоит забыть о классической модели логов. Докер активно продвигает философию "один контейнер - один процесс" (и, судя по разделению сервер со статикой / приложения, вы и без меня это знаете), сам контейнер *и есть то, что вы в нем запускаете*. Благодаря этому больше не нужно складывать логи в отдельные файлы, заниматься их ротацией и прочее - нужно просто выкидывать все напрямую в stdout, а докер уже сам позаботится о хранении и ротации (для этого, правда, придется указать некоторые опции контейнеру) логов. Кроме того, это позволяет скинуть кучу проблем администрирования по сбору этих логов - достаточно просто собирать их с указанных контейнеров, а что там валяется - вообще без разницы. Я уж молчу про то, что если логи сразу отправляются по сети куда-либо, минуя файлы, то это тоже дает значимый прирост скорострельности. Да и `docker logs --tail 100 abcd`, как правило, выполняется быстрее нахождения нужного файла.
Благодаря той же философии вам не нужно заботиться о пользователях. У вас есть root, и он может делать внутри системы все, что захочет, внутри **просто нет иерархии пользователей, у которых есть разные права**. Даже если кто-то обнаружит уязвимость в приложении и сломает контейнер, перезапустить его - дело десяти секунд. `/etc/passwd` хоста все равно не угнать.
По поводу разработки в докер-контейнерах - честно сказать, я пытался это внедрить у себя, но не взлетело по ряду причин (java и так маскирует в себе все внешние зависимости, запускаясь веб-сервером сама по себе; дебаггер IDEA ведет себя куда приятней на обычном run, нежели remote run).

Закончу ссылкой на [12-factor app](http://12factor.net/ru/), концепцию, которая продвигает очень близкие докеру по духу стандарты.

Comment: В последнее время много хорошего про докер слышу и читаю. Кстати, ссылка хорошая, спасибо.

Comment: /etc/passwd -> /etc/shadow, конечно